# How to pass object into implements and pass out the local object?

Tags: java, oop, swing, object, implements

How do I pass a object to an implement and pass the local object to object that is outside? I think the SwingUtilities.invokeLater is nessasary for a Swing object , right?

```
  Sensors sens = new Sensors();

  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    GUI application = new GUI(sens);
    application.getJFrame().setVisible(true);
   }
  });

  SMS sms = new SMS(application);
```

this is me try to solve the problem , but i get a **No enclosing instance of type GUI is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type GUI (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of GUI).** problem.

```
// in main
Sensors sens = new Sensors();
GUI application = null;
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GUIthread(sens , application));
SMS sms = new SMS(application);


//a class inside GUI.java , but not inside GUI class
class GUIthread implements Runnable{
  Sensors s;
  GUI g;
  public GUIthread(Sensors s , GUI g){
   this.s = s;
   this.g = g;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   g = new GUI(s);
   g.getJFrame().setVisible(true);
  }
 }
```

the [sourcecode](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15075769/src.rar)

Comment: is `GUIthread` a local inner class, or is it separate?

Comment: edited , sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem arises when you try to create an instance of a non-static inner class in a context that does not specify (or imply) an instance of the enclosing class.

From this, I deduce that you have declared one of your classes as a non-static inner class; e.g. something like this:

```
public class Outer {
    ...
    public class Inner {
        public Inner() {
           ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If you now try to create an instance of `Inner` in some other code using `new Inner()`, you will get a compilation error like the one you are seeing.

You can do one of two things to "fix" the problem:

- If you change `public class Inner {` to `public static class Inner {`, you can use `new Inner()` as you are currently doing.  But this will mean that the code of `Inner` cannot access the (final) instance variables of the enclosing class; i.e. `Outer`.
- If you don't want to change `Inner` to a static class, you will need to instantiate it as follows:

  ```
  Outer outer = ...
  ...
  Inner inner = outer.new Inner();  // qualified creation
  ```

**FOLLOWUP**

> any down side using static class to call swing?

Only the one that I identified above.

> SO , all the instantiate happen inside Outer constructor? right?

No.  The code in the "qualified creation" example above can appear anywhere that the `Inner` class is accessible.  And since we declared it as `public` ...

If you instantiate `Inner` inside a constructor (or instance method) for `Outer`, you can just use `new Inner()`.  The enclosing `Outer` instance is the same as `this`.

Comment: any down side using static class to call swing? SO , all the instantiate happen inside Outer constructor? right?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
final Sensors sens = new Sensors();
```

instead.

Comment: but final means cannot be change , i have a thread running to change the value inside the Sensors object.

Comment: @wizztjh - see my comment on @Alice Young's answer.  This is not your immediate problem.

Comment: can you pass me the link , it doesn't show the name of the person who ask in SO profile ...

Comment: Sensor can, of course, change. The final keyword here just means that this _reference_ can't change and point to something else later. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, declare the reference final and it will be seen by the anon class code.

Comment: This is not the problem.  If it was, the OP would see an compilation error at a different point complaining about use of a non final reference in an enclosing class.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Zach and suspect that GUIthread is an inner class.  If so, you may do well to make it a stand-alone class or a static inner class, but it's difficult to know if this is the true solution without more information and without the actual error message.